# TypeScript generic method with type dependent parameter

Tags: typescript, generics

I have an idea to have a code that automatically checks type of parameter based of generic type of the method. But the type of the parameter should be the same as type of concrete property of given generic type. Let me show you example.

let's say i have these interfaces:

```
interface IMessage {
    name: string,
    payload: any
}

interface IConcreteMessage {
    name: "concreteMessage",
    payload: string
}
```

And I'd like to call some method acception IMessage as generic parameter this way:

```
someobject.genericMethod<IConcreteMessage>(78)
```

Now the question is, how the method should be declared so the compiler throws an type error for given parameter?

```
public genericMethod<T extends IMessage>(payload: ??) {}
```

And the second thing - can I somehow extract the "concreteMessage" value within the method only from given generic parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a type query to achieve this:

```
genericMethod<T extends IMessage>(payload: T['payload']) { }

someobject.genericMethod<IConcreteMessage>(78) // will be an error
```

You can' get a string at runtime from a literal string type, you will need to pass a string value as a parameter.

Comment: I tried that but for some reason it was not working before but now it is.... Anyway thanks. And what about the second question - accessing "name" value without passing it directly? Is this even possible?

Comment: @mikeek that is not possible, added that to the answer

Comment: OK than, the more I'm thinking about that the worse feeling I have about this approach... Thank you very much :)

Comment: @mikeek it's a pretty common approach actually .... you can't get the string but you can constrain the caller to be able to only pass you taht particular string

Answer (score 0):

OK so I've ended up with this solution:

```
genericMethod<T extends IMessage>(name: T['name'], payload: T['payload']) { }
```

the drawback is that I need to enter the first parameter with each call even when this property is constant but I think I can live with that